# mean function producing same result

Tags: r, dplyr

the mean function is acting weird, it is constantly producing 0.3880952

```
H10 <- H10 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(t10dv = mean(c(fd$DV1_C, fd$DV2_C, 
                        fd$DV3_C, fd$DV4_C), 
         na.rm = TRUE))

head(H10)

            DV1_C           DV2_C         DV3_C           DV4_C     t10dv
            <int>           <int>           <int>           <int>     <dbl>
1               1               0               0               1 0.3880952
2              -1               0               2              -1 0.3880952
3               0               0               0               0 0.3880952
4               0               2               1               1 0.3880952
5              -1              -1              -1              -2 0.3880952
6              -2               0               0               0 0.3880952
```

Comment: You're using c(fd$DV1_C, fd$DV2_C, fd$DV3_C, fd$DV4_C) which is taking the full data. Just use c(DV1_C, DV2_C, DV3_C, DV4_C) to keep the rowwise operation in place assuming you wanted to get the row mean for those four values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is simply:

```
H10$t10dv <- rowMeans(H10[c("DV1_C", "DV2_C", "DV3_C", "DV4_C")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, your mutate call compute the mean of the concatenation of your four columns (`c(fd$DV1_C, fd$DV2_C, fd$DV3_C, fd$DV4_C)`.

If you need to compute the mean of each column, you need to make 4 calls.

```
mutate(x = mean(fd$DV1_C), 
       y = mean(fd$DV2_C), ... etc.
```

Best

Colin

Comment: Sorry Colin, I am trying to compute the mean of a scale.